# QT : Insert data to table by user in c++

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, qt

I have written the following code to insert data into table (DB_TABLE_NAME ). 
point 1. table name is defined as MACRO
point 2. i don't know it is correct or not

can anyone tell me

```
int Database::DatabaseInsertToTable(QString& timestamp, QString& jsonData)
{ 
  QSqlQuery toInsetTable;   
  toInsetTable.prepare(QString("INSERT INTO" DB_TABLE_NAME 
                     (timestamp,jsonData)+("VALUES(?,?)")));

  toInsetTable.bindValue(0, timestamp);
  toInsetTable.bindValue(1, jsonData);
  bool result=toInsetTable.exec( );
  if( result)
  {
    qDebug() << "Successful inserted \n";
    return (0);
  }
  else
  {
    qDebug() << "insert failed \n";
    return (-1);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? In case your code does not work, please provide the error you're getting and the expected output

Comment: You string looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah you are correct String was wrong...but now i corrected..it's working fine